# Angular nested route paramMap subscriptions

Tags: angular, rxjs

I think this is a more `rxjs` related question, but I'm facing it in my Angular App.

we have in our application nested subscription of router event.

I'll try to explain step-by-step how the code works.

We have a DropDown with a list of contracts.
And we have a DropDown with a list of years.

Once the user change the selection in the contracts DropDown we need to navigate and put the contract id in the URL with the selected contract id, then we have to load the years related to this contract id, we subscribe to the router event:

```
this.activatedRoute.parent.paramMap
  .map(m => +m.get("contractId"))
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .subscribe(contractId => {
      // CALL SERVICE TO LOAD DROPDOWN WITH YEARS
  })
```

The user can also change the year in the years DropDown.

Once the user change the selection in the years DropDown, we also have to navigate and update the URL with the selected year, then we need to load a grid with data, that is how it looks:

```
this.activatedRoute.parent.paramMap
  .map(m => +m.get("contractId"))
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .subscribe(contractId => {
      // CALL SERVICE TO LOAD DROPDOWN WITH YEARS

      this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap
        .map(m => +m.get("year"))
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .subscribe(year => {
        // CALL SERVICE TO LOAD GRID WITH DATA
      })
  });
```

The problem here is that everytime the contract id changes, I create a new subscription of the `this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap`, that means, several duplicated http requests.

I also tried using `unsubscribe` but the DropDown with the years won't trigger the subscription anymore when the selection changes.

What is the best way to solve such a nested call?

**EDIT**:

I fixed it - not so elegantly IMO:

```
let subscription = new Subscription();

this.activatedRoute.parent.paramMap
  .map(m => +m.get("contractId"))
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .subscribe(contractId => {
      subscription.unsubscribe();

      // CALL SERVICE TO LOAD DROPDOWN WITH YEARS

      subscription = this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap
        .map(m => +m.get("year"))
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .subscribe(year => {
        // CALL SERVICE TO LOAD GRID WITH DATA
      })
  });
```

Maybe `rxjs` offers a more elegant way of solving this?

**EDIT:**

I created a plunker to ilustrate the scenario:

https://plnkr.co/edit/Z3AqcayxSALiWGoI7KRE?p=preview

Comment: Any way you could build a plunker to demonstrate this?

Comment: Sure, I'll do this.

Comment: Hello @DeborahK - here we go with the plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/Z3AqcayxSALiWGoI7KRE?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was using `switchMap` instead of several `subscribers`, here we go:

```
this.activatedRoute.parent.paramMap
.map(m => +m.get("contractId"))
.distinctUntilChanged()
.switchMap(contractId => {
  // CALL SERVICE TO LOAD DROPDOWN WITH YEARS

  return this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap
    .map(m => +m.get("year"))
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .switchMap(year => {
    // CALL SERVICE TO LOAD GRID WITH DATA
  })
}).subscribe(() => {});
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I spent some time with the Plunker. I updated the ngOnInit as follows:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    let contractId;
    let year;

    this.activatedRoute.parent.paramMap
        .subscribe(params => {
          this.contractId = params.get('contractId');
          console.log("Selected contract Id: " + this.contractId);
          // Code to populate the years from the contractid
        })

    this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap
      .subscribe(params => {
        this.year = params.get('year');
        console.log("Selected year: " + this.year)
        if (this.year) {
          this.loadGrid(this.contractId, this.year);
        } else {
          // Clear grid??
        }
      });
  }
```

The first subscription watches for changes to the contract and gets new years.

The second subscription watches for changes to the year query parameter and reloads the grid.

I don't think you want one within the other because that adds multiple subscriptions.

Is this what you were trying to achieve?

Updated plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/7Pn6HX3D6fZ8iHdylbUW?p=preview

Comment: Thank you very much @DeborahK.  I forgot to mention: When the contract changes, I need to load the years DropDown again, as every contract has a different range of years. Sorry for forgetting this important point and that is why this code of you won't work. In my point of view it has to be nested. Question is how to handle the subscriptions. I could fix this by always unsubscribing in every contract change, but it "smells" IMO as I'm too lay in `rxjs`.

Comment: I understood that from your original post. Hence the text "Code to populate the years from the contractId" in my code above. I don't understand why that would cause the need to nest the subscriptions? By nesting them you are creating a new subscription every time the user changes the parent. You could then have dozens or more subscriptions watching and trying to execute.

Comment: Maybe you could update the plunker I provided and demonstrate how it does not work in your scenario? Then I can look at how to edit it.

Comment: This would work only when we change the values of the DropDowns, but once the app starts (ngOnInit) - let's assume with year in the route - then the grid will be loaded twiced. I hope I could make it clear and I hope I'm not overcomplicating things.

Comment: How would it be loaded twice? Can you show me in the plunker? Are you calling `this.loadGrid` somewhere else as well?

Comment: Sure, here we go, just click on Initialize route:

https://plnkr.co/edit/K2I6E6jqPKdvbd9hy9cm?p=preview

Comment: First, don't pass in a valid year when you first navigate. Instead try something like this: `<a [routerLink]="[1000, 'Parent']" [queryParams]="{ year: 0} ">Initialize route</a>` Because at this point, you don't have a valid year anyway, right? Then you can change the if so only call `LoadGrid` if it is a year > 0. Finally, instead of calling `LoadGrid` directly, update the query params. That will cause it to use the existing code and won't call it twice.

Comment: We do have a valid year, the user receiveis a complete URL with the contractId and the year per email. The user should be able to click on that link and land in that page. Maybe instead o using observables then using promises? Then on `then` I would select the correct year? I would rather move this discussion to a chat if you think it makes sense.

Comment: Sure, I'll keep working on this regarding (even tho I've found a workaround for that) and I'll post it here and tag you. Thank you so much for your help and time